# Perform sever-side caching of 3rd party images

Tags: caching

I just added some functionality to [my site](http://www.libcompass.com/) which, when a user hovers their mouse over a link (to a 3rd party page), a preview of the link is created from the meta tags on the target page and displayed.  I'm worried about the implications of hot-linking in my current implementation.

I'm now thinking of implementing some kind of server-side caching such that the first request for the preview fetches the info and image from the target page, but each subsequent request (up to some age limit) is served from a cache on my host.  I'm relatively confident that I could implement something of my own, but is there an off-the-shelf solution for something like this?  I'm self-taught so I'm guessing that my DIY solution would be less than optimal.  Thanks.

**Edit** I implemented a DIY solution (see below) but I'm still open to suggestions as to how this could be accomplished efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any off-the-shelf solutions so I wrote one in PHP.

It accepts a URL as a HTTP GET parameter and does some error checking.  If error-checking passes, it opens a JSON-encoded database from disk and parses the data into an array of Record objects that contain the info that I want.  The supplied URL is used as the array key.  If the key exists in the array, the cached info is returned.  Otherwise, the web page is fetched, meta tags parsed, image saved locally, and cached data returned.  The cached info is then inserted into the database.  After the cached info is returned to the requesting page, each record is examined for its expiration date and expired records are removed.  Each request for a cached record extends its expiration date.  Lastly, the database is JSON-encoded and written back to disk.